# Sum elements of linked list x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, linked-list, x86

I know this question has been asked many times tonight, but none of the questions seem to have been resolved. Obviously it's a homework question, but it really wasn't thoroughly explained in class, hence the flood of questions on this topic. The goal is to implement a function which sums together the positive elements of a linked list, and return the result.

I'm able to get the head pointer from the stack and put it into EBX, the problem is I'm not sure how to move to the next node of the linked list, and also I'm not sure how to check if the end of the linked list has been reached. If anybody could steer me in the correct direction that would be much appreciated! My current code, comments included, is below.

```
__declspec(naked) int positiveSum(struct Node *head) {
    __asm{

    PUSH EBX
    MOV EAX, 0

    MOV EBX, [ESP+8] // put pointer from stack into ebx
    ADD EAX, [EBX] // add value in first node to eax

    POP EBX

    ret
    }
}


struct Node{
int e;
struct Node *next;
};


struct Node * createList(int * Arr, int len) {
if (len == 0) {
    return NULL;
}

struct Node *head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
head->e = Arr[0];

struct Node *tail = head;

for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    struct Node *next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    tail->next = next;
    tail = next;
    tail->e = Arr[i];
}
tail->next = NULL;

return head;
}
```

Comment: Oops, didn't copy it sorry I'm a mess tonight. It's there now

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you all doing the same course?

Comment: I guess we just aren't a social generation

Comment: Assume ebx is a pointer to a node as shown in the code example, then [ebx] is the same as (* Node)->e, and 4[ebx] or [ebx+4] is the same as  (* Node)->next. I've posted a partial example of the assembly code in an answer to similar question earlier.

Comment: What exactly is [ebx+4] getting? (I'm not that familiar with linked lists)

Comment: mov eax,[ebx] => eax = (Node *)->e ... mov eax,4[ebx] => eax = (Node *)->next == pointer to next node or zero. If you're not familiar with linked lists, try writing a test program in C or C++ first, then do the assembly version.